# OS Closed my native thread?

Tags: android, android-ndk

As far as I know the OS closes threads if it is low on memory.
1) Is is true for native threads that was started using pthread?
2) If so, how can I know if the OS closed a thread?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know the OS closes threads if it is low on memory

Not as far as I am aware. Android will terminate your entire process when it is low on memory, not individual threads.